# Getting JSON in nested ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The http request sent to some 'request_url' returns json response in format {'succes': 1, 'html': 'thestuff'}

so when

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'request_url',
   success: function(response){
      alert(response.html); //'thestuff' is here as expected
   }
});
```

'thestuff' can be found in response.html as expected. But if this ajax is called inside the 'success' callback of another one ajax request then the response.html is coming empty and 'thestuff' is going to 'response'.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'some_other_url',
   success: function(some_other_response){
       jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'request_url',
        success: function(respose){
          alert(response.html);    //there is nothing
          alert(response);         //I see 'thestuff' which is expected in 'html' 
        }
     }) 
   }
});
```

Why does it happen?

Update: 'thestuff' contains some js code with {} I can suppose something can get confused but why it works well with single (not nested) ajax request.

Comment: numerous typos in all the variables `respose0` vs `response` vs `respose`. Hard to know what's what. Suggest you name them differently in each success handler while debugging and readability but make differences more obvious

Comment: I would suggest that one url is returning json and the other is returning html or you need to set the `dataType` to match what is sent. What errors are thrown?

Comment: This could be because you are using asynchronous calls, and when you are trying to execute another ajax call on the success, the first call haven't finish yet, so it starts the second one (even in a success callback) something like that happen to me before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment so adding as an answer
Here is expanding on charlietfl comment of using dataType.

I made it work using dataType="json". Json has to be strictly formatted though as per jQuery documentation.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'some_other_url',
   success: function(some_other_response){
      jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'request_url',
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(response){
           alert(response.status);    //there is nothing
           alert(response);         //I see 'thestuff' which is expected in 'html' 
         }
      }) 
    }
});
```

request_url should return something like this (note, quotes should be used instead of apostrophes)

```
{"status":"s","html":"some stuff"}
```